# Minimizing and restoring a form while showing another form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have 2 forms, one of them is being showed through clicking a button in the first one. I want it such that when the button for showing 2nd form is clicked, first form gets minimized, and the second form opens normally. And when the 2nd form is being closed, the first window should become un-minimized and be placed where it was before.

User can override this and just click on the first form in quick luanch area and bring up the first form if he/she wants, so I dont want the 2nd from to me of Dialog kind.

I am trying the code below, but when I click on the button, the 1st form gets minimized, and also the second form is being minimized too! so I have to manually un-minimize 2nd form!

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DebugForm != null)
            return;

        DebugForm = new DebugForm();
        DebugForm.Closed += delegate
                                 {
                                     WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                                     DebugForm = null;
                                 };

        WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        DebugForm.Show();
        DebugForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        DebugForm.BringToFront();
    }
```

Comment: I think this can be done using `internal` methods in both forms. reply me if i am wrong. (i have done the same in my project)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to minimize both windows when there is another window on your screen. Minimize all windows except your application. You will see that it works. Keep it working along with other windows like this:

Change this:

```
WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
DebugForm.Show();
DebugForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
DebugForm.BringToFront();
```

to this:

```
DebugForm.Show();
WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

The lines I removed weren't really necessary. The important thing is the order of statements to coordinate with the Z order of the parent form before minimizing it.

Comment: By Z order, I mean the front to back order of the windows stacked on your screen. In other contexts, it means the Z order of controls within their parent. The BringToFront method you used would have worked had DebugForm been a child control of the parent form, but it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into similar issue. The problem was that the form I was trying to call back was not an active form. Here's how I solved the issue. On the button click of the current from2 I added:

```
if (form1.ActiveForm == null)// Check to see if form is active
{
    form1 frm = (form1)Application.OpenForms["form1"];// find open form
    frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;// Set state
    frm.ShowInTaskbar = true; //set to show in taskbar
}
```